# Join two tables in HIVE with sub query

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I need to get the cost of an item at a certain date and time. I have these two tables:

`create table sales ( product_id int, items_sold int, date_loaded date );
create table product ( product_id int, description string, item_cost double, date_loaded date );`

The product table is a history of each item. If the cost of an item today is $1.00 but the cost of that item yesterday was $0.99 I would have two records one for each day. When I load my sales data I need to reflect the cost of the item yesterday and not today's cost.

Here is the query I am trying to execute:

`SELECT s.product_id, s.items_sold, p.description, s.items_sold * p.item_cost as total_cost FROM sales s, product p 
WHERE 
    p.product_id = s.product_id and 
    p.date_loaded <= (
        SELECT MAX(pp.date_loaded) 
        FROM product pp 
        WHERE 
            pp.product_id = s.product_id and 
            pp.date_loaded <= s.date_loaded
    )`

SALES TABLE:

`|PRODUCT_ID  |ITEMS_SOLD |DATE_LOADED |
 |1           |4          |2016-06-30  | 
 |1           |5          |2016-07-01  |
 |1           |6          |2016-07-02  |
 |1           |3          |2016-07-03  |`

PRODUCT TABLE:

`|PRODUCT_ID  |DESCRIPTION |ITEM_COST   |DATE_LOADED | 
 |1           |ITEM A      |0.99        |2016-06-20  |
 |1           |ITEM A      |1.00        |2016-07-02  |`

I would expect to see this result:

`|PRODUCT_ID  |ITEMS_SOLD |DESCRIPTION |ITEM_COST   |TOTAL_COST  |
 |1           |4          |ITEM A      |0.99        |3.96        |
 |1           |5          |ITEM A      |0.99        |4.95        |
 |1           |6          |ITEM A      |1.00        |6.00        |
 |1           |3          |ITEM A      |1.00        |3.00        |`

From everything I have read this form of a sub query is not allowed. So how can I accomplish this in HIVE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be accomplished with [CTE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Common+Table+Expression) and [Lag widow function](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics)

```
     With result as(select PRODUCT_ID, DESCRIPTION, ITEM_COST , DATE_LOADED ,
     LEAD(DATE_LOADED, 1,'2999-01-01')
     OVER (ORDER BY DATE_LOADED) AS fromdate from PRODUCT ) 
     SELECT s.product_id, s.items_sold, p.description, s.items_sold * p.item_cost 
     as total_cost  FROM sales s join result p on s.product_id = p.product_id 
     where s.DATE_LOADED >= p.DATE_LOADED  and s.DATE_LOADED < p.fromdate  ;
```

[image: result]

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of only returning one row per sales record. It's still going to return all rows less than or equal to the fromdate. The way it's written it actually returns 0 records. Your last date_loaded I am assuming that is from the result set.

Comment: example you have shred  is also having one record per sales table is there ..  can you please let me know what is wrong in result set ..

Comment: This is the error I get when I run this:
 H110 Unable to submit statement. Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups. At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for circular dependencies. Underlying error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Line 3:48 Invalid table alias or column reference 'DATE_LOADED': (possible column names are: ) [ERROR_STATUS]

Comment: I have update the query there was missing "from PRODUCT  "

Comment: Still doesn't work:

H110 Unable to submit statement. Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10017]: Line 7:12 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN 'fromdate' [ERROR_STATUS]

Comment: I changed it to this:
With result as(select PRODUCT_ID, DESCRIPTION, ITEM_COST , DATE_LOADED ,

LAG(DATE_LOADED, 1,'1990-01-01') OVER (ORDER BY DATE_LOADED) AS fromdate from PRODUCT 
)

SELECT s.product_id, s.items_sold, p.description, s.items_sold * p.item_cost as total_cost FROM sales s join 
result p on s.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE s.DATE_LOADED >= p.fromdate and s.DATE_LOADED < p.DATE_LOADED;

An I was able to get two of the sales records but not all 4.

Comment: Hi now try i have changed lag to lead  LEAD

Comment: It looks like it works but when I add another part to the where clause it doesn't seem to work properly. I added a where s.date_loaded > '2016-06-01' on my full data set and I only got 3 rows back. I have a few million records after that date on the sales table any thoughts

Comment: tell your full problem ... i doubt you are not putting filter on rt place..